# Setting keyboard shortcut to maximize Acrobat window in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I set a keyboard shortcut to maximize windows using the System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts feature in OS X, specifically setting a 'App Shortcuts' under 'All Applications' to the item 'Zoom' (using the key combination cmd+ctrl+M), **however this does not work in Adobe Acrobat Pro X11**.  I realized that Acrobat has another menu item (under View->Zoom), that may be conflicting, so I found the '->' notation and changed the shortcut definition specifically to 'Window->Zoom', which is where the maximization feature is located in Acrobat and other OS X programs.  With or without the '->' in the shortcut definition, the keyboard shortcut works for most applications (e.g. TextEdit), but not for Adobe Acrobat.  Any idea **how to get it to work in Acrobat as well?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12). It's one of my favorite applications for window management. You can set whatever shortcut you would like for maximizing and it works for all of my apps. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is *not* possible using any of the existing, built-in tools (of the OS or the App).
Unfortunately, Adobe is validating its reputation of being difficult by going out of their way- investing resources- to **prevent** any customization of shortcuts using even the system preferences!  They weren't satisfied to merely "leave out" any interface or method of keyboard shortcut customization for their software (including Acrobat), which I find especially frustrating, disturbing and unnecessary.

Fortunately, various solutions/work-arounds seem to be available using 3rd party software- which I've found to be quite stable in OS X.